# PermissionError: Access is denied: 'C:\\users\\#username#' using the getpass module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the youtube_dl module to download youtube videos. I want to get the name of the user executing the file so I can complete the path to the directory:

```
import __future__, youtube_dl, getpass

username = getpass.getuser()
url = input('Url: ')

options = {'outtmpl': 'C:/users/"username"/Desktop/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s',}
```

But when I execute it, I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\users\\#username#'
```

How can I solve this problem without having to run the file as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with actual privileges, but rather the path you are trying to write to. You have used `getuser`, but you haven't put it in the `outtmpl` string. You probably want to do something like this:

```
options = {'outtmpl': 'C:/users/{username}/Desktop/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'.format(username=username),}
```

Which will use the actual user name running the program instead of a constant `"username"` string.